# xWebSite LogPeriod error in IIS 7.5

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7.5, powershell-dsc

I am getting an error setting the log file rollover schedule for a web site in IIS 7.5 using PowerShell DSC. The following script

```powershell
Configuration TestConfiguration
{
    Import-DscResource –ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xWebAdministration

    Node localhost
    {
        WindowsFeature IIS
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Name = "Web-WebServer"
        }

        xWebsite DefaultSite
        {
            Ensure    = "Present"
            Name      = "Default Web Site"
            LogFormat = "W3C"
            LogPeriod = "Hourly"
            DependsOn = "[WindowsFeature]IIS"
        }
    }
}
```

gives me the error:

*Hourly is not a valid value for Int32*

I don't get the error when the target setting is already Hourly and the error doesn't occour in IIS 8.0. My environment is:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
- IIS 7.5
- Powershell 5.0
- xWebAdministration 1.17.0.0

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed by [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/xWebAdministration/pull/300) pull request and released in the [xWebAdministration 1.18.0.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xWebAdministration/1.18.0.0).